# Finding 'BA' and 'AB' in one string without overlapping

Tags: python, find, sequence

I search for my answer in stackoverflow and another sites but i couldn't find my answer.
*I don't want to use libraries, i want more simple answer*.

**it must do this:**
get 'ABBA' and print('YES') / get 'BAAB' and print('YES')
/ get 'ABA'  and print('NO')  / get 'ABHA' and print('NO')

I write this code:

```
str = input().upper()
a = str.find('AB')
b = str.find('BA')


if ('AB' in str ) == True:
    a = a+2 and 'BA' in str[a:] == True
    print('YES')

if ('BA' in str ) == True:
    b = b+2 and 'AB' in str[b:] == True
    print('YES')

if ('AB' in str[b:]) == False:
    print('NO')
elif ('BA' in str[a:]) == False:
    print('NO')
```

my code prints lots of 'YES's!!

Comment: Please re-take the intro tour; pay special attention to [how to ask(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).and [minimal, reproducible example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In particular, note that "it doesn't work" is not a problem specification.  "I want to write better code" and "can you help me" are not Stack Overflow questions -- you need to ask a specific question.  Give us a MRE and we can help.  "Please fix this code I found somewhere else" is not a proper posting here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of matching strings is often best solved by a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

It's also good practice to separate your algorithms (*e.g.* evaluation, calculation, matching, creating data structures, etc.) from your side effects (*e.g.* printing) as this enables unit testing.

The code below should solve your problem:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'^.*(AB.*BA|BA.*AB).*$')

def isABBA(s):
    return regex.match(s) is not None

assert isABBA('ABBA')
assert isABBA('BAAB')
assert not isABBA('ABA')
assert not isABBA('ABHA')

for i in ['ABBA','BAAB','ABA','ABHA']:
    print('YES' if isABBA(i) else 'NO')

# Output:
# YES
# YES
# NO
# NO
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you:

```py
s = input()
s= s.upper()

f_AB = s.count('AB') #Frequency of "AB"
f_BA = s.count('BA') #Frequency of "BA"

if f_AB != 0 and f_BA != 0:
    a = s.find('AB')
    b = s.find('BA')

    if f_AB > 1 and f_BA > 1:
        print('YES')
    elif (a-b == 1) or (a-b == -1):
        print('NO')
    else:
        print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input().upper()
i = 0
count, count_1 = 0, 0
while i <= len(s):
    if s[i:i+2] == 'AB':
        count += 1
        i += 2
    elif s[i:i+2] == 'BA':
        count_1 += 1
        i +=2
    i += 1
if count == 1 and count_1 == 1:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```